# Puppet stdlib module file_line doesn't have an effect

Tags: ubuntu, debian, automation, puppet

I have the following module:

```
include stdlib
class pulseaudio-zeroconf {
        package { "pulseaudio-module-zeroconf":
                ensure => installed
        }

        file_line { "pulseaudiozeroconfdiscoverentry":
                path => "/etc/pulse/default.pa",
                line => "load-module module-zeroconf-discover",
                ensure => present,
        }
}
```

The package `pulseaudio-module-zeroconf` is installed but somehow `file_line` has no effect on `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

We know for sure that the module is executed: If we introduce an error to the module, puppet throws an error.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 with Puppet 2.7.11

Puppetmaster: Debian Squeeze with Puppet 2.7.17 and stdlib 2.3.2 (we tested several versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We managed to solve this issue by enabling pluginsync in the puppet config on the puppethosts.

```
#puppethost:/etc/puppet/puppet.conf 
[main]
#...
pluginsync=true
```